# In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False

Tags: python, django, angular

I create realtime chat application using websocket frontend(angular) backend(Django).. i want to store messages in to db(mySql)..when i trying to store message array from angular to django..it give me error like 500 internal server Eroor and In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False.
i sending message data in list array.. so what is wrong?

model.py

```
class msg(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1200)
    myDate = models.DateTimeField()
```

serializer.py

```
class MesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=False, slug_field='name', queryset=User.objects.all())
    receiver = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=False, slug_field='name', queryset=User.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = msg
        fields = '__all__'
```

view.py

```
class msg_list(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        mes = msg.objects.all()
        serializer = MesSerializer(mes, many=True)  # convert into JSON
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, formate = None):
        data = JSONParser().parse(request) #type list
        serializer = MesSerializer(data= data, many = True) #type list
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

and when i open message api:
[image]

Comment: Title does not match the question. :/

Comment: Please make sure the title of the question matches the actual error you are getting.
The error "In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False" is obtained when you try to return non-dictionary data via JsonResponse or HttpResponse. This can be solved by making safe=False.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to parse request before serializing. Just pass `request.data` as serializer argument:

```
def post(self, request, formate = None):
    serializer = MesSerializer(data=request.data, many=True) #type list
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

**UPD**

`receiver` is CharField, so you cannot use `SlugRelatedField` for it. Just use default `CharField` for it in serializer also:

```
class MesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=False, slug_field='name', queryset=User.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = msg
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: thankss.. but now error is detail
:
"Unsupported media type "text/plain" in request."  415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: @Jolly You need to set `content-type` header `application/json` on the frontend side.

Answer (score 10):

When we return data as `JsonResponse(...)` from your view, Django's `JsonResponse()` expects your JSON data to be in key:value pairs. For example:

```
class Login(APIView):
     def get(self,request):
     ................
     token = 'abcd'
     return JsonResponse(token)
```

but here the variable `token` is not a dictionary with key:value pair, thus `JsonResponse` has to be told  "hey this isn't the regular key value but it's not a mistake, I intentionally want to send a single value as json."

So to tell that to `JsonResponse` we need to pass set `safe=False`:

```
class Login(APIView):
     def get(self,request):
     ................
     token = 'abcd'
     return JsonResponse(token, safe=False)
```

If you don't want to specify that in your return statement, you can use the ordinary `Response()`.

```
class Login(APIView):
 def get(self,request):
 ................
 token = 'abcd'
 return Response(token)
```